# MVVM / PRISM: Where should dialog box strings be stored?

Tags: wpf, forms, xamarin, mvvm, prism

I'm building an application using PRISM and MVVM.  I have a view model that needs to display a non-modal dialog box to the user indicating an operation is in progress.  I'm using essentially an abstracted IDialogService.

My question is:  where should I store the strings for the title and the message shown in this dialog box?  The view model's logic causes the dialog box to be displayed and determines when it should be closed.  Hence, I have code that looks like this in my view model:

```
let! closeDlgAction = 
            dialogSvc.ShowDialogModeless (
                "Opening File",
                "Please wait while your selected file is opened.") |>  Async.AwaitTask
```

I'm thinking about localization scenarios.  WPF has its own mechanism for providing localization through resource dictionary, etc.  It seems like these strings belong in a resource dictionary, but the view model shouldn't have a dependency on WPF resource directories - especially because the same view model is going to be used on a Xamarin Forms application later.

The best solution that comes to mind is to use a service that abstracts the resource library away (e.g. IDialogStringService), but I wonder if there's a better or more preferred approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use resource dictionaries (xaml) to store text. Instead you have to use Resources (*.resx). In VS:

1. Right click on project
2. Add -> New Item...
3. Find "Resources File" template, type name, and click Add
4. Opt. Open this file (special editor will opened) and on top bar switch Access Modifier to Public, if you want get access to text from another project or from XAML. Add some key\value strings.
5. Right click on resource file and click **Run Custom Tool**. New class will generated with static properties with names based on your keys from Step 4.

How to use (if file has name Localizations.resx and has string with key "AppTitle")

From code:

```
let! closeDlgAction = 
            dialogSvc.ShowDialogModeless (
                Localizations.AppTitle,
                "Please wait while your selected file is opened.") |>  Async.AwaitTask
```

From xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="{x:Static Localizations.AppTitle}"/>
```

*.resx file and *.cs file that is generated both don't depend on any WPF assemblies, so you can use them in different assemblies: in shared view models, from wpf views and from xamarin views. Just put you *.resx file in separate netstandard assembly and refer to it where do you need it from
[image]

Cons of this way:

1. resx generates class with strings and each string is public property, so static code analyze works
2. You don't have add new abstraction level
3. You can ref strings from code files or from XAML

Comment: This is, of course, the correct way, but `Localizations` should be hidden behind a service when used in code, as @vgeglia suggested. Otherwise it might get hard to write the tests for the code that wants to show the dialog.

Comment: @Haukinger I think we can avoid adding new abstraction level. I added details in answer

Comment: if you have a developer language (and you really should), then I think it's not that evil to make static references to the resources

Comment: @Vadim thank you for the answer, I marked it as the answer but my reputation is too low yet for SO to show it.  :-(

I had used the same approach you recommended previously on a Windows Forms app, and it seemed to be a fine approach.  My only concern with it here, is it feels like the localization concern is decentralized somewhat.  The Views will have their own localization, and now the View Model (in a separate library) will have its own string resources.

Answer (score 0):

I liked Vadim's answer, and I have used that approach before.  If my View Models lived in the same project as the WPF project, that would be the best solution.

However, my View Models are in a different library (and a different language) and will be shared between a Prism MVVM WPF project and a Prism MVVM Xamarin Forms project.  I could still use resources in the View Model library, but then localization concerns would exist separately in both the WPF project (for the Views) and the View Model library.  IMO the localization concern should be centralized.

As such, I decided to abstract the resources behind a service. Implementing the resource service turned out to be more straightforward than I thought.  To use an indexer intuitively, I defined a "resource container object" that is returned by IResourceService, as seen below:

```
public struct ResourceContainer
{
    private readonly Func<string, string> _resourceGetter;

    public string this[string resourceId] => _resourceGetter(resourceId);

    public ResourceContainer(Func<string, string> resourceGetter) => _resourceGetter = resourceGetter;
}

public interface IResourceService
{
     ResourceContainer Resources { get; }
}
```

And the service implementation in the WPF library is as follows:

```
 public class ResourceService : IResourceService
{
    public ResourceService()
    {
        Resources = new ResourceContainer((s) => Application.Current.Resources[s] as string);
    }

    public ResourceContainer Resources { get; }
}
```

In the WPF layer's XAML resource directory:

```
<s:String x:Key="FileOpenDialogTitle">Opening File</s:String>
<s:String x:Key="FileOpenDialogMessage">Please wait while your selected file is opened.</s:String>
```

And, finally, the View Model consumes this service by requesting IResourceService on its constructor, and is used as follows:

```
 let! closeDlgAction = 
            dialogSvc.ShowDialogModeless (
                resourceSvc.Resources.["FileOpenDialogTitle"],
                resourceSvc.Resources.["FileOpenDialogMessage"]) |> Async.AwaitTask
```

This approach will ultimately require implementing the resources twice - once for the WPF project and once for the XF project, but I have to implement the Views twice, anyway.  At least the localization concerns are centralized in both cases (or perhaps a shared resource library can be used between both projects).

EDIT:  This technique could also leverage Vadim's suggestion by putting the localization resource (.resx) in the WPF project as well, and either having the XAML resource directory reference the static resources, or have the ResourceService return the resource directly.  Having the resources in .resx format may make sharing them between multiple projects more straightforward.

Comment: I'd be interested in what you plan to do to detect typos in the string literals you use to access the resources... other than having testers literally review each and every screen in each and every state for each and every version.

Comment: @haukinger, very good point.  The resource service should accept a typed object (enum perhaps?) instead of a string literal.

Comment: strings are fine, but they should come from properties like those produced by the resx-code generator